# Angular standalone component importing module error

Tags: angular, treemodel, angular-standalone-components

Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules. Here treemodule is up to date but still getting the error . [this is the error caused in component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITx0A.png)

[This is he error caused in main.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h27oS.png)

Answers for the above question

Comment: Try "re-start" the `ng serve`. When we add a library to angular.json generally we need "re-start" to take account the changes. NOTE: I feel that `@circlon/angular-tree`are not ready to use with standalone components.